# How to enable Android monitor?

Tags: android, memory, android-studio, android-debug

I wanted to see how much memory consume my application but when I open Android Monitor it's showing this monitor is disabled even my application running on device and also selected in debuggable application

[image]

[image]
Already Enabled ADB integration

[image]

I am wondering how to enable it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can Simply Go To  **Tools > Android > Android Device Monitor**  in That Monitor you can find tabs like **System Information** or **Heap**. Is this answer your question?

### Update:

another way you can have it. like this 
Eclipse Preferences (OSX) > Android > DDMS > check Thread Updates Enabled by Default

Add Android Device view to get device pan(e) noted above

Set android:debuggable=true (two g's) in app tag as noted above

Run your app in emulator

Select device in device pane

Click the update threads button

Comment: Thanks for your answer, No this is not , you can see in below window there is option Memory and CPU, in memory window showing this monitor is disable. why and how to enable?

Comment: @Ajit can you tell me whether you able to open DDMS?

Comment: Yes I am able to open DDMS.

Comment: @Ajit There you can have Allocation Tracker and System Information Tabs right? (I think it's better then memory tab in Android Studio)

Comment: Yes there is Allocation Tracker and System Information tabs

Comment: In your updated answer you want to say in Eclipse or android studio?

Comment: @Ajit You can use it to see Memory consumed by your App. (Please make sure that you've select your proper device in left panel called "Devices".) also If it it not showing any update then you can restart ADB by  Click on "Reset ADB" Option in left panel Heading with reverse triangle image.

Comment: @Ajit my mistake it was for Eclipse

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92057/discussion-between-greenrobo-and-ajit).

Comment: Many thanks for your support. Some thing is wrong with Android Studio I don't know how, working fine. Today I am able to see CPU and Memory Graph in this window.

Comment: @Ajit Glad to know that you got what you wanted!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  Here's hoping this fix works for you.

In the Android Monitor controls, it looks like you have selected a dead process. In my case, I had selected a disconnected emulator instead of the device I wanted to monitor. Double check that you have selected the correct device and process.

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio 3.5+ there is no Memory Monitor, instead there is Profiler.

Comment: The original question was about Android Studio 1.4, not 3.5. You answer is not really answering that question for this older version of Android Studio.

Comment: Android Studio 1.4 is not mentioned in the question, we can see the version only from the screenshot. As anybody who tries to find Memory Monitor in Android Studio 3.5+ following the steps in the answers , I was very confused. My answer clarifies the situation.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter this problem recently, it is enable after I have setup SDK of my project in "Project Structure".